# Interact with Amazon App on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, amazon-appstore

Does anybody knows if there is a way to interact with Amazon App ? I want to give ability to my users to buy stuff on amazon, and instead of sending them to the web version of amazon, I would like to use the Amazon App, if installed on device. It should be a broadcast receiver on which I should pass an amazon's OfferListeningId...

I did not find any kind of documentation on this app anywhere !

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself...

I've 'explored' the app, and there is absolutely no BroadcastReceiver on this app (on version 2.0.2). Too bad.